# UIView contents not updating in UIKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I have a `UIView` which I am passing data from another view using `getData(data: MydataModel)`. The data arrives at the second view but with a delay.

Here my sample code:

```swift
class MyView: UIView {

  var myData: MydataModel?

  init() {
    loadView()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }

  func getData(data: MydataModel) {
    self.myData = data
  }

  func loadView() {
    label.text = myData?.city
  }

}
```

I tried using property observer but I run into issues and not updating content inside the view.

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question: Note that the method `loadView()` is defined by UIViewController. If you define it, the system calls it when it is time for your view controller to provide its view hierarchy. Given that that method name is used by UIViewController, I would suggest using a different name to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it was just an example. To show what I was doing I have a different name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that calling `getData(data:)` only sets the `myData` variable - it doesn't update any visible content in the view.
You can add a property observer to `myData` that calls `loadView` to update the view:

```swift
var myData: MydataModel? {
  didSet {
    loadView()
  }
}
```

If you're still running into issues, make sure that all view updates are happening on the main thread, so perhaps you need call `getData(data:)` within `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: It saved the day working fine now, thank you.